# How to change button text in pyqt5 when clicked with keypress

Tags: python, pyqt5

So currently I am creating Sudoku in PyQt5. So, far I have Board.py which just generates new boards. Currently I am working on Play.py, which should be able to click on empty squares and be able to change it with the press of a keyboard button(keypress). In Play.py I have finished everything - All the numbers are put into a board and I am able to click on buttons and it initiates a keypress. But, the way I coded it, all the buttons are stored into a list (I did this because I wanted the code to look clean) and it only updates the last button. Instead of it updating the last button, I would like it to update the button that was most recently clicked.

I have tried many things but what I have narrowed it down to currently is to find the position of the button in the list of all buttons(all_buttons) and do something from there but I'm not sure. So, how would I be able to take the key press and put it into the button that was recently pressed?

Here is Board.py. It just generates new boards it is unnecessary to look at.

```
import random
import numpy as np


# populates a row in random spaces
def populate():
    row = [0] * 9
    num_in_box = random.randint(3, 6)
    while True:
        spot = random.randint(0, 8)
        r = random.randint(1, 9)
        if r not in row:
            row[spot] = r
        if row.count(0) == (9 - num_in_box):
            break
    return row


# populates a grid in random spaces - has duplicates in column, row and box
mapped = list()
for x in range(9): mapped.append(populate())


# checks every number in column and row and returns numbers in list
def col_row_nums(array, row, col):
    check_col = [j for j in array[:, col] if j != 0]
    check_row = [i for i in array[row] if i != 0]
    if array[row][col] in check_col:
        check_col.remove(array[row][col])
    return check_col + check_row


# checks every number box and returns numbers in list
def box_nums(array, box_row):
    reshaped_box = np.reshape(array, (27, 3))
    list_boxes_in_rows = list()
    for a in range(3):
        for b in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                p2 = list(np.reshape((reshaped_box[c::3]), (3, 9)))
                for d in range(3): list_boxes_in_rows.append(p2[a])
    array_boxes_in_rows = np.array(list_boxes_in_rows)
    return [k for k in array_boxes_in_rows[box_row] if k != 0]


# removes any duplicates so each column, row and box all have only one set of numbers 1 - 9
def finalize_board():
    box_rows_num = -1
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            box_rows_num += 1
            arr = np.array(mapped)
            possible_nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            col_row_duplicates = list()
            box_duplicates = list()
            used_nums = set(col_row_nums(arr, x, y)) | set(box_nums(arr, box_rows_num))

            for w in used_nums:
                col_row_count = col_row_nums(arr, x, y).count(w)
                box_count = box_nums(arr, box_rows_num).count(w)
                if col_row_count > 1: col_row_duplicates.append(w)
                if box_count > 1: box_duplicates.append(w)
            if mapped[x][y] in col_row_duplicates or mapped[x][y] in box_duplicates:
                remaining_nums = list(set(possible_nums) - set(used_nums))
                if len(remaining_nums) > 0: mapped[x][y] = random.choice(remaining_nums)
    return mapped
```

Next is Play.Py.

```
import sys
from pynput import keyboard
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

import Board


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        all_buttons = list()
        layout = qtw.QGridLayout()
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        board = Board.finalize_board()
        y_num = -1

        for x, rows in enumerate(board):
            for y, cell in enumerate(rows):
                y += 1
                if cell == 0: cell = ' '
                button = qtw.QPushButton(str(cell), self)
                button.setFixedHeight(100)
                button.setFixedWidth(100)
                layout.addWidget(button, x, y)
                if cell == ' ':
                    button.clicked.connect(lambda: pressed())
                    button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #e3efff; color: black;}')
                else:
                    button.setEnabled(False)
                    button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #ebebeb; color: black;}')
                all_buttons.append(button)


        def pressed():
            with keyboard.Events() as events:
                # maybe - ?? HOW TO RETURN POSITION OF BUTTON IN ALL_BUTTONS
                event = events.get(1e6)
                x = event.key
                print(str(x))
                button.setText(str(x))

        self.setLayout(layout)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Use `keyPressEvent` [click here](https://learndataanalysis.org/example-of-how-to-use-the-qwidget-keypress-event-pyqt5-tutorial/).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget)
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(chr(event.key()))

    def test_method(self):
        print('Space key pressed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = MainWindow()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`event.key()` will always return an integer. You can use the built-in `chr(int)` function to get the key, the problem is we can't identify keys other than alphabets and numbers. If you want other keys as well, use conditions.

```
   def keyPressEvent(self, event):
       if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
           print("Space pressed")
   # Qt.Key_Shift for shift key, Qt.Key_Control for Ctrl key.
```

<s>HERE IS THE FINAL CODE:</s> read edit2

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
import Board


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        all_buttons = list()
        layout = qtw.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        board = Board.finalize_board()
        y_num = -1

        for x, rows in enumerate(board):
            for y, cell in enumerate(rows):
                y += 1
                if cell == 0: cell = ' '
                button = qtw.QPushButton(str(cell), self)
                button.setFixedHeight(100)
                button.setFixedWidth(100)
                layout.addWidget(button, x, y)
                if cell == ' ':
                    button.setCursor(qtc.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
                    button.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.mousePressEvent(event)
                    button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #e3efff; color: black;}')
                else:
                    button.setEnabled(False)
                    button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #ebebeb; color: black;}')
                all_buttons.append(button)

        self.last_clicked = ''
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.show()
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        k = (chr(event.key()))
        self.last_clicked.setText(k)
        self.last_clicked.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3efff; color: black;")


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        widget = self.childAt(event.pos())
        widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3efff; color: black; border: 1px solid red")
        print(widget.pos())
        self.last_clicked = widget
        return qtw.QWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now when you press a key, it updates the text of the recently clicked button. You might want to add some try except to the `keyPressEvent` and `setText function`

---

**EDIT 2**:
I don't exactly know why the first button gets selected, I'm guessing something's wrong with the `mousePressEvent`. It first returns the first widget and then the actual button that was clicked. I tweaked a few things and it now works fine.

Stuff I changed:

- I created a new list `self.available_buttons`. It contains all the empty/clickable buttons.
- Whenever an empty button is pressed, the code goes through the list and searches for `last_clicked` widget. If the `last_clicked` widget is found, it highlights the button and changes all other buttons to normal(no border color).

```py
class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        all_buttons = list() # contains all buttons
        self.available_buttons = list() # contains clickable buttons
        layout = qtw.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        board = Board.finalize_board()
        y_num = -1

        for x, rows in enumerate(board):
            for y, cell in enumerate(rows):
                y += 1
                if cell == 0: cell = ' '
                button = qtw.QPushButton(str(cell), self)
                button.setFixedHeight(100)
                button.setFixedWidth(100)
                layout.addWidget(button, x, y)
                if cell == ' ':
                    button.setCursor(qtc.Qt.PointingHandCursor)
                    button.mousePressEvent = lambda event: self.mousePressEvent(event)
                    button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #e3efff; color: black;}')
                    self.available_buttons.append(button) # appends empty buttons to the list
                else:
                    button.setEnabled(False)
                    button.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #ebebeb; color: black;}')
                all_buttons.append(button)

        self.last_clicked = ''
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        k = (chr(event.key()))
        self.last_clicked.setText(k)
        self.last_clicked.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3efff; color: black;")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        widget = self.childAt(event.pos())
        self.last_clicked = widget

        for button in self.available_buttons:  #searches for clicked button
            if widget == button:
                button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3efff; color: black; border: 1px solid red") # adds border to clicked button
            else:
                button.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3efff; color: black;") # all the other buttons go back to their normal state

        return qtw.QWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        # -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please ping me if you face any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much I did not know about keyPressEvent. There is a problem, whenever a button anywhere on the screen is clicked, the first button activates aswell even if it superposed to be grayed out. What could the reason be for this?

Comment: @SakethGanji Sorry didn't notice it. I fixed it and posted a new code. Refer EDIT 2 in my original answer.